# How to create multi-value attribute in a HDF5 file using C++ API

Tags: c++, hdf5

**EDIT STARTS**

I'm trying to create an "pair, triplet or n-uplet" attribute based on a native type (float, int...) :

- pair of float, triplet of float, n-uplet of floats attribute
- pair of int, triplet of int, n-uplet of int attribute

I'm not trying to create an "Array" attribute, I'm not trying to create a "Compound" attribute

**EDIT END**

I'm trying to create an attribute based on a native type (float, int...) but which contains 2,3 or more values (equivalent to a pair or a n-uplet).

**I don't want to create an array ! I want to create something very similar to an array, but not the same**

I can create single value attribute this way (for a "double" attribute) :

```
H5::DataSpace dataSpace = H5::DataSpace();
H5::Attribute attribute = group.createAttribute(attributeName, H5::PredType::IEEE_F64LE, dataSpace);
attribute.write(H5::PredType::IEEE_F64LE, &attributeValue);
```

To create a couple of "double", I've tried this :

```
hsize_t dimension;
dimension = 2;
H5::ArrayType dataType(H5::PredType::IEEE_F64LE, 1, &dimension);

H5::DataSpace dataSpace = H5::DataSpace();
H5::Attribute attribute = group.createAttribute(attributeName, dataType, dataSpace);

double attributeValue[2];
attributeValue[0] = x;
attributeValue[1] = y;

attribute.write(dataType, attributeValue);
```

But it creates an **array type attribute** in the HDF5 file.

I know it's possible to create an attribute whcih contains multiple values because I can do it using the HDFView GUI software (the first one is created using the above code, the second line is an attribute created using the GUI - I want to create this kind of attribute) :

[image]

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without exactly knowing what you are trying to accomplish, I believe what you are looking for is a self-defined datatype using the HDF5 compound datatype H5::CompType, which is usually used to save simple structs. Taken from the [HDF5 C++ compound example page](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/compound_8cpp-example.html), the struct

```
  typedef struct s1_t {
    int    a;
    float  b;
    double c;
  } s1_t;
```

has the associated compound datatype:

```
  CompType mtype1( sizeof(s1_t) );
  mtype1.insertMember( MEMBER1, HOFFSET(s1_t, a), PredType::NATIVE_INT);
  mtype1.insertMember( MEMBER3, HOFFSET(s1_t, c), PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
  mtype1.insertMember( MEMBER2, HOFFSET(s1_t, b), PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT);
```

Compound datatyped are then treated the same way as native datatypes and may also be saved as attributes.

**Edit**

The error you made in your code above was to define your datatype to be saved as an H5::ArrayType when you didn't actually want to save an Array. What you really want is a simple datatype (such as PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE) saved in a higher dimensional dataspace.

```
#include "H5Cpp.h"

#ifndef H5_NO_NAMESPACE
  using namespace H5;
#ifndef H5_NO_STD
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;
#endif  // H5_NO_STD
#endif  
const H5std_string FILE_NAME("save.h5");
const H5std_string ATT_NAME("Attribute");

int main(){
  const hsize_t dims=5;
  int ndims=1;

  DataType dtype=PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE;

  H5File h5file(FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_TRUNC,H5P_DEFAULT,H5P_DEFAULT);

  DataSpace* dspace = new DataSpace(ndims,&dims);
  Attribute att=h5file.createAttribute(ATT_NAME,dtype,*dspace);
  delete dspace;

  double attvalue[dims];
  for(auto i=0;i<dims;++i) attvalue[i]=i;

  att.write(dtype,attvalue);
  h5file.close();

  return 0;
}
```

This should reproduce the "createdUsingHDFVIEW" attribute above (except for the datatype). I can't check to make sure as I dont have HDFView. This didn't occur to me at first as I tend to think of H5::DataSpace as a type of array (which it actually is).

Comment: I'm not trying to create a compound datatype. I'm trying to create a pair, a triplet, a n-uplet... It's easy to do using "HDFView" GUI, but I can't find how to do it using the API.

Comment: @Aurelien If you are not looking for an array (as you have written above) the only other possible way to achieve what you are looking for that I know of would be the use of compound datatypes. I think you are actually looking for an array here. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: I've just tested. It works excatly like expected... I feel like a dumb because I haven't thought to change the DataSpace's dimension. Thanks !