# How to write multi-valued data in HDF5

Tags: c++, dataset, hdf5

I was working in C++ with HDF5 and I need help in saving multi-valued data. As I am not entirely sure if this is the best method, I wanted to try to save the data as an compound type in the original dataset (like written in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35597759).

My Code looks like this at the moment (strings are entirely for testing):

```
#ifdef WITH_HDF
#include <iostream.h>
#else
#include <iostream>
#endif
#include <string>
#include "H5Cpp.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace H5;

const int LENGTH = 1;
const int RANK = 1; 
const string FILE_NAME = "fhirBASIS.h5";

/**Compound datatype with datatypes*/
struct observation_t
{
    char* status; 
    char* device;
    char* code; 
    char* value; 
    char* system; 
    char* version; 
    int userSelected;
    char* subject;
    char* effectiveDateTime;
};


/*
 * Code start
 */

int main(){

    H5File file("fhirBASIS.h5",H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
    Group grp(file.createGroup("SensoricData"));

    observation_t observation;

    //status string
    std::string dts = "status";
    observation.status = new char[dts.length()];
    observation.status = const_cast<char*> (dts.data());

    //device string
    std::string dtd = "device";
    observation.device = new char[dtd.length()];
    observation.device = const_cast<char*> (dtd.data());

    //code string
    std::string dtc = "code";
    observation.code = new char[dtc.length()];
    observation.code = const_cast<char*> (dtc.data());

    //value string
    std::string dtv = "value";
    observation.value = new char[dtv.length()];
    observation.value = const_cast<char*> (dtv.data());

    //system string
    std::string dtsys = "system";
    observation.system = new char[dtsys.length()];
    observation.system = const_cast<char*> (dtsys.data());

    //version string
    std::string dtver = "version";
    observation.version = new char[dtver.length()];
    observation.version = const_cast<char*> (dtver.data());

    //userSelected bool
    observation.userSelected = 0; 

    //subject string
    std::string dtsub = "subject";
    observation.subject = new char[dtsub.length()];
    observation.subject = const_cast<char*> (dtsub.data());

    //effectiveDateTime string
    std::string dtedt = "effectiveDateTime";
    observation.effectiveDateTime = new char[dtedt.length()];
    observation.effectiveDateTime = const_cast<char*> (dtedt.data());


    // create spatial structure of data
    hsize_t len = LENGTH;
    hsize_t dim[1] = {len};
    DataSpace space(RANK,dim); 

    // write required size char array and declare datatypes
    H5::StrType datatype(H5::PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE); 
    hid_t strtype = H5Tcopy (H5T_C_S1);
    H5Tset_size (strtype, H5T_VARIABLE);

    //defining the datatype to pass HDF55
    H5::CompType mtype(sizeof(observation_t));
    mtype.insertMember("status", HOFFSET(observation_t, status), datatype);
    mtype.insertMember("device", HOFFSET(observation_t, device), datatype);
    mtype.insertMember("code", HOFFSET(observation_t, code), datatype);
    mtype.insertMember("value", HOFFSET(observation_t, value), datatype);
    mtype.insertMember("system", HOFFSET(observation_t, system), datatype);
    mtype.insertMember("version", HOFFSET(observation_t, version), datatype);
    mtype.insertMember("userSelected", HOFFSET(observation_t, userSelected), PredType::NATIVE_INT);
    mtype.insertMember("subject", HOFFSET(observation_t, subject), datatype);
    mtype.insertMember("effectiveDateTime", HOFFSET(observation_t, effectiveDateTime), datatype);

    DataSet dataset =  grp.createDataSet("Observations",mtype,space);
    dataset.write(&observation,mtype);
    dataset.close();
    space.close();
    mtype.close();
    grp.close();
    file.close();

    return 0; 
}
```

I want to achieve, that I can store multiple values i.e. for the data "status". I tried this by creating an compound datatype and edited the status value to use it. This does not work, but I don't know how to fix it. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be a beginner in HDF5. I recommend that you start with native types (non-compound types), and then after you master that, move to compound types. Besides, the h5group have tons of examples; have you looked there? Also, as a subjetive advice: Use the C-interface of HDF5. The C++ interface is not as popular and as good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TheQuantumPhysicist . I am fairly new, but am already quiet familiar with datatypes. I need this structure of data for the project I am working for, as well as c++ (instead of c). I already read like every of their examples, they lead me to where I am at the moment. I know about the chunks, dataspaces and all sorts of theory, but I just need to store multi valued data (Basically as shown in the linked thread). That's what I need, thanks nonetheless.

Comment: You don't have to use a C compiler to use the C-interface. Remember that C++ is a superset of C. I understand that you need compound datatypes for your application, but I think if you succeed in creating examples with native datatypes and understand them fully, this will help you progress faster. Good luck!

Comment: I did the examples, but I am just not able to write a compound datatype into another compound datatype as mentioned here: https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.intro.html (A compound datatype is one in which a collection of several datatypes are represented as a single unit, a compound datatype, similar to a struct in C. The parts of a compound datatype are called members. The members of a compound datatype may be of any datatype, including another compound datatype. It is possible to read members from a compound type without reading the whole type.) Thaks for your help @TheQuantumPhysicist